# Primary Key matching returns ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a procedure that fetches all of the related fields into variables. The code is simplified as below.

```
PROCEDURE pr_update(new_id IN NUMBER) 
AS 
v_a NUMBER;
v_b NUMBER;
v_c NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT APPRVD_1, TOT_1, NEW_1 
    INTO v_a , v_b , v_c
    FROM TableName 
    WHERE TABLE_ID = new_id;
END pr_update;
```

If I call this procedure from another procedure with a new_ID transferred in, it will throw an error
ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than the requested number of rows
But if I put the new_id directly in the where clause, it can work fine.

`WHERE TABLE_ID = 1213;`

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Well, the query can't find more than one row unless your assumption is wrong and the table_id is not a unique key. Try `select table_id from tablename group by table_id having count(*) > 1`. This must return no rows.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Tried that. Really nothing returns. I guess the problem is at the input param new_id IN NUMBER. If I directly replace the new_id with an id value. the procedure works okay. But just does no work if I transfer that value in. Not sure why...
And if I put dbms_output.put_line('<< Executingpr_update ID ' || new_id);
I can see the id value is correct.

Comment: That is strange. I cannot think of many scenarios. If there is a unique constraint on the table_id, you cannot get this error with the query shown. It is just not possible. So, either the constraint is missing and you insert a second row and then get an error with the query or you have significantly altered the query for the purpose of demonstration or or the error happens elsewhere. Don't know.

Comment: Could you, please, post **real** WHERE clause from that procedure? I presume that column / parameter names aren't really named TABLE_ID and NEW_ID.

Comment: Also ensure that TableName maps to the same object when compiled in that procedure as it does when you are testing it ad-hoc. Be sure to be logged in as the same user, or fully qualify the table name with an owner name to make sure. Ask if there is any VPD policy in place that could be masking what you see when you query ad-hoc. Check all_tab_constraints to ensure you have either a P or U constraint on the column, or at least an index in all_indexes with uniqueness = UNIQUE. And lastly, as Littlefoot suggests, try giving us the exact SQL without changing it - any change could impact behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Without all the details its hard to say, but a common issue here is data type mismatch.  If "TABLE_ID" is a varchar2, then doing something like

```
where TABLE_ID = my_numeric_variable
```

will silently be converted to

```
where to_number(TABLE_ID) = my_numeric_variable
```

which means that (for example) values '01' and '001' will be match and create the error you're seeing.